# Codeigniter Router $this->uri->segment not working exactly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two-way access:

```
1 : http://website.com/main/selectBaivietTag/video/chon-loc/2 //$this->uri->segment(5)=2
2 : http://website.com/video/tag/chon-loc/2 //$this->uri->segment(5)=1
```

And my router

```
$route['([a-z\-]+)/tag/([a-z\-]+)/(:num)']='main/selectBaivietTag/$1/$2';
$route['([a-z\-]+)/tag/([a-z\-]+)']='main/selectBaivietTag/$1/$2';
```

I want access the second but $this->uri->segment(5)=2 not =1, Please help me!
Thanks alot!

Comment: try $this->uri->segment(4) for 2nd url you will 2

Comment: oke, tks you :) very very much... it great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use

for the first link

```
1 : http://website.com/main/selectBaivietTag/video/chon-loc/2
```

you can get your value with this

```
$this->uri->segment(5)
```

this will give your value i.e. 2
but for second links

```
2 : http://website.com/video/tag/chon-loc/2
```

you can get your value with this

```
$this->uri->segment(4)
```

this will give your value i.e. 2

Comment: I am using the same thing you said..its working in one place but it doesnot pick my iD passed in URL in another file.. why..?

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
$this->uri->rsegment(5); :))
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: Thanks you for reply, but not working... I use $this->uri->rsegment(5); for 2nd is not display

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
<?php 
      $segment = $this->uri->segment_array(); 
      echo $segment['5']; 
?>
```

Working fine for me.